# Do I need to add more gas piping and shut off valve in kitchen?

Tags: plumbing, gas

Moved into a new house and noticed the gas supply to where the stove will go does not have a shut off valve, and the piping only extends ~2 inches above the floor. The shut off valve for this line is accessible in the basement underneath. My questions are:

- Do I need to install a shut off valve in the kitchen, above the floor?
- Is this something I can safely DIY?

[image]

Comment: "Need" to would indicate you're looking for a code requirement, right? We need to know where in the world you live to help determine if code requires that, so [edit] it into your question. Whether this is something _you_ can safely DIY depends on _you_, making that subjective, opinion based, and therefore off-topic. There are loads of questions here about DIY gas plumbing, so look through them and decide for yourself. While you're editing in your locale, please remove that part because we can't answer that. Unless, of course, your locale _prohibits_ DIY gas work...

Comment: Aaaand, a shutoff in the basement means that you don't have to pull the stove out to do a shutoff, so at a minimum, common sense would have you *add* a shutoff if you wanted.

Comment: You have _a_ gas shutoff valve for this individual appliance, so practically speaking (without knowing your local code), no, you don't "need" a valve right behind the stove. However, you might _want_ one for added convenience. In my house, getting to the root cellar basement isn't really convenient, so having one directly behind the stove might be a nice "want". OTOH, pulling the stove out to get to the valve might be more of a hassle than going to the basement at _your_ house. Therefore, this boils down to a code requirement & barring that, opinion...

Comment: OK, you said what I said much more succinctly and to the point... ;) +1